# Find most favored area on an image

Tags: php, algorithm, math, statistics

What mean-stat-equation should I use when I have an image with N-number sample-size of selections?

I have a unique problem for which i was hoping to get some advice, so that i don't miss out on anything.
The Problem: To find the most favored/liked/important area on an image based on user selection of areas in different selection ratios.

Scenario: Consider an [Image of a dog](http://www.kelowna.ca/CM/AssetFactory.aspx?did=9133), and hundreds of users selecting area over this image in various resolutions, the obvious area of focus in most selections will be the area containing the dog. I can record the x1,x2,y1,y2 co-ordinates and put them into a db, now if i want to automatically generate versions of this image in a set of resolutions i should be able to recognize the area with the max attraction of the users.
The methods i think could work are:

1. Find the average center point of all selections and base the selection in that. - Very simple but would not be as accurate.
2. Use some algorithm like K Means or EM Clustering but i don't know which one would be best suited.

Looking forward to some brilliant solution to my problem

More info on the problem:
The Actual image will be most probably be a 1024x768 image, and the selections made on it will be of the most common mobile phone resolutions. The objective is to automatically generate mobile phone wallpapers by intelligent learning based on user selections.

Comment: What result are you hoping to achieve and present? 5 top box areas, colored "hotspot" areas or something else?

Comment: The actual image will be much higher in resolution and i am hoping to generate wallpapers for mobile phones using user inputs automatically.

Comment: What result would you like if 2 corners are equally popular selection areas? Take one of the corners or an area between them?

Comment: Like this? http://uxmag.com/articles/eye-tracking-the-best-way-to-test-rich-app-usability. Not sure how eye-tracking ties into php.

Comment: When I first heard the question I was thinking about the Yahoo network ad which change in x and y depending on where you hold your mouse, but that nor your eye tracking is the case here. He OP wants the position and size of the most "obvious" area of an image (based on user selection).

Comment: @Robert- Good point, hadn't thought of that, but majority of images will have a very big difference between two selections so i guess i'll pick up the more popular one. or maybe present both if need be.

Comment: There are many thoughs regarding this question, and you may have to fill up a bit more. Will the selection area be fixed in size, or can it be 10x10 aswell as 5x100 ? If people like to do a "weird" selection, that won't fit on your wallpaper.

Comment: Ok, i realise now how little i put up there, 
The selections will be constraint bound by predefined ratios, they will not be the same ratios however, they will be the most common mobile phone resolutions and the outputs will be generated for the same resolutions.

Comment: By "selecting an image", I presume you mean "determine the visible portion of an image" based on the viewer's resolution?

Comment: Selecting would mean creating a selection area using Javascript.

Comment: So really.. the question is just "How can I get my users to draw a box on images and then show the most-selected portion".

Comment: Is this crowd-sourced cropping software?

Comment: Not exactly crowd sourcing, the users have the freedom to create their own wallpapers based on their selections and while they are at it, i can analyse the data and make the best match for upcoming users to save them the effort.

Comment: You may be looking for [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) values.

Comment: @eggyal averaging is very tricky, if the half of the users select the top right corner and the other half select the bottom left corner then the focus would be in the center of the image wich is off interest ....

Comment: @MikeB The question is how can i find the most selected area, not just based on average. Have to remove the noise.

Comment: @eggyal Of course.. I was intentionally trivializing a question that, imho, needed it. Now that it's been reduced to its simplest form we can get onto what StackOverflow is about.. specific programming problems. So instead of more comments about how to maybe implement this kind of system we can pose concrete questions like "What mean-stat-equation should I use when I have an image with N-number sample-size of selections?" - Easy to understand, no extra-reading or comprehension required.

Comment: @MikeB Good Point, Post updated.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: I said "*some form* of averaging" specifically because I assumed a simple mean would not suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have **two** distinct problems identified above:

**ONE: Identification of Points**

For this, you will need to develop some sort of heuristic for identifying whether a point should be considered or not.

I believe you mentioned that hundreds of users will be selection locations over this image? Hundreds may be a lot of points to cluster. Consider excluding outliers (by removing points which do not have a certain number of neighbors within a particular distance)

Anything you can do to reduce your dataset will be helpful.

---

**TWO: Clustering of Points**

I believe that K Means Clustering would be best suited for this particular problem. 
[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

Your particular problem seems to closely mirror the standard Cartesian coordinate clustering examples used in explaining this algorithm.

What you're trying to do appears to be NP-Hard, but should be satisfied by the classical approximations.

Once clustered, you can take an average of the points within that cluster for a rather accurate approximation.

**In Addition:**

You dataset sounds like it will already be tightly clustered. (i.e. Most people will pick the dog's face, not the side of it's torso.) You need to be aware of local minima. [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Discussion) These can really throw a wrench into your algorithm. Especially with a small number of clusters. Be aware that you may need a bit of dynamic programming to combat this. You can usually introduce some variance into your algorithm, allowing the average points to "pop out" of these local minima. [Local Minima/Maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_minimum)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm going to have to do a lot of studying before i can implement this, but yeah pretty much what i thought and much more!

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean. I'm a student majoring in Robotics Engineering and Computer Science, focusing in artificial intelligence. So, if you've got $50k a year to spare, I'll put in a good word for you at school

Comment: Lol.. if i had $50k a year to spare i wouldn't be asking this question, would have hired a team by now.. :P

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to approach your problem in a different way.  If you have not heard of [Seam Carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving) then I suggest you check it out, because the data you have available to use is perfectly suited to it.  The idea is that instead of cropping an image to resize it, you can instead remove paths of pixels that are not necessarily in a straight line.  This allows you to resize an image while retaining more of the 'interesting' information.

Ordinarily you choose paths of least energy, where energy here is some measurement of how much the hue/intensity changes along the path.  This will fail when you have regions of an image that are very important (like a dog's face), but where the energy of those regions is not necessarily very high.  Since you have user data indicating what parts of the image are very important you can make sure to carve around those regions of the image by explicitly adding a little energy to a pixel every time someone selects a region with that pixel.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NcIJXTlugc) shows seam carving in action, it's cool to watch even if you don't think you'll use this.  I think it's worth trying, though, I've used it before for some interesting resizing applications, and it's actually pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Very very interesting! however most of the images will contain majorly faces and humans and this kind of resizing would distort their faces. But surely applicable to so many more things i have in mind! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Suyasha: But that's why your situation is so great, if you've got humans telling you what regions of the image are important then you can avoid that problem.

Comment: i'll run some tests on the images and if it works then awesome!! I'm currently looking up its php implementation, found nothing of use yet..

Comment: Just found Imagick::liquidRescaleImage dying to get my hands on it

Comment: Liquid resize majorly distorts images with humans but pretty cool with nature images.